# initialising Basic GUI in Python (using tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a menu but this just shows a blank GUI, what have i done wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        menu = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)
        submenu = Menu(menu)

        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)

        subMenu.add_command(label="Nothing", command=SayNothing)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

    def SayNothing(self):
        print("Nothing")

root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I fixed a typo which now makes it display the 'File' but it doesn't show the submenus correctly

Comment: Typos XD, anyway it's gotten better but it still hasn't made the submenus work do you know how i could fix that?

Comment: I think that people are downvoting your question b/c it seems clear that you didn't try to run it, at least, not in the form that you posted here.  The code that you posted above will not run!  If you make the corrections that the python interpreter suggests, you wouldn't have required a post on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

When mispellings and scoping are corrected, it works just fine:

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        menu = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)
        subMenu = Menu(menu)

        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)

        subMenu.add_command(label="Nothing", command=self.SayNothing)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

    def SayNothing(self):
        print("Nothing")

root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

- `subMenu` should be consistently spelled
- `command=self.SayNothing`, not `command=SayNothing`

Answer (score 0):

First off, `submenu` is case sensitive. So you must reference it as `submenu` not `subMenu` unless you re-define it. In addition, you defined `SayNothing` after you referenced it.

This should solve all your problems.

```py
from tkinter import *

def SayNothing():
    print("Nothing")

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        menu = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)
        subMenu = Menu(menu)

        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)

        subMenu.add_command(label="Nothing", command=SayNothing)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```